# How can I connect the lines in tikz tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a tikz tree diagram. Can some one tell me how can I connect the update block down and from above and how to change the Yes and NO conditions. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.2cm, text width=4em, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start initialization of model};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=start] {Initialise the operating current mode};
\node (prop2)[process, below of=pro1] {Call the input variables of the whole system from the scripts};
\node (prop3) [process, below of=prop2] {Call the initial setpoins for the individual components};
\node (prop4) [process, below of=prop3] {Simulate the individual sub-systems };
\node (prop5) [process, below of=prop4] {Calculate derivatives};
\node (prop6) [process, below of=prop5] {Calculate output state variables};
\node (prop7) [process, below of=prop6] {Store the values in work-space};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=prop7,node distance=2.3cm] [draw, align=center]{Simulation \\ completed};
\node [block, right of= prop7, node distance=6cm] (update) {update model};
\node (prop8) [process, below of=dec1,node distance=2.3cm] {Store the iteration outputs of all state variables in work-space};
\node (prop9) [process, below of=prop8] [draw, align=center]{Considering the stored final output state variable \\ as initial condition for main model simulation};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=prop9] {End initialization};
\draw[arrow] (start) -- (pro1);
\draw[arrow] (pro1) -- (prop2);
\draw[arrow] (prop2) -- (prop3);
\draw[arrow] (prop3) -- (prop4);
\draw[arrow] (prop4) -- (prop5);
\draw[arrow] (prop5) -- (prop6);
\draw[arrow] (prop6) -- (prop7);
\draw[arrow] (prop7) -- (dec1);
\draw[arrow] (dec1) -- node {no}(prop8);
\draw[arrow] (dec1) -- +(6,0) |- node[near start] {yes} (prop5);
\draw[arrow] (prop8) -- (prop9);
\draw[arrow] (prop9) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not tree diagram ... the more correct name is *flowchart* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum 
 height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum 
 height=0.8cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.2cm, text 
 width=4em, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start initialization of model};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=start] {Initialise the operating current 
mode};
\node (prop2)[process, below of=pro1] {Call the input variables of the whole 
system from the scripts};
\node (prop3) [process, below of=prop2] {Call the initial setpoins for the 
individual components};
\node (prop4) [process, below of=prop3] {Simulate the individual sub-systems 
};
\node (prop5) [process, below of=prop4] {Calculate derivatives};
\node (prop6) [process, below of=prop5] {Calculate output state variables};
\node (prop7) [process, below of=prop6] {Store the values in work-space};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=prop7,node distance=2.3cm] [draw, 
align=center]{Simulation \\ completed};
\node [block, right of= prop7, node distance=6cm] (update) {update model};
\node (prop8) [process, below of=dec1,node distance=2.3cm] {Store the 
iteration outputs of all state variables in work-space};
\node (prop9) [process, below of=prop8] [draw, align=center]{Considering the 
stored final output state variable \\ as initial condition for main model 
simulation};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=prop9] {End initialization};
\draw[arrow] (start) -- (pro1);
\draw[arrow] (pro1) -- (prop2);
\draw[arrow] (prop2) -- (prop3);
\draw[arrow] (prop3) -- (prop4);
\draw[arrow] (prop4) -- (prop5);
\draw[arrow] (prop5) -- (prop6);
\draw[arrow] (prop6) -- (prop7);
\draw[arrow] (prop7) -- (dec1);
\draw[arrow] (dec1) -- node[right] {no}(prop8);
\draw[arrow] (dec1) -| (update);
\draw[arrow] (update) |-node[right, near start]{yes}(prop5);
\draw[arrow] (prop8) -- (prop9);
\draw[arrow] (prop9) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is solve by @js bibra answer, so there are some off-topic comments and suggestions how you can make your flowchart more nice (according to my taste) and make code shorter:

- use of the `tikzstyle` is deprecated. instead use `\tikzset` (see MWE below)
- main branch of flowchart's nodes are in chain, so for their positioning is handy to use the `chains` library
- the `chains` library offer the `join` macro by which you can simply connect nodes in the main branch of the flowchart
- for node out of chain you need to discontinue the `join` macro, for example with code *suspend join* as is used in the MWE below

**Edit (1):**

- If in real document use default page layout determined by `article` document class, than flowchart fit in page
- In the MWE below is added option for showing page layout, which confirm above statement
- In the case, that your document use for example bigger fonts or the text area is smaller you have the more possibilities:

  - increase width of nodes (that text in some nodes is one line only)
  - reduce font size, for example from `\small` used in MWE to `\footnotesize`
  - reduce vertical distance between nodes (now is 5mm)

**Edit (2):**
improved styles definitions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
       base/.style = {draw, rounded corners,
                      text width=##1, minimum height=9mm,
                      align=flush center, outer sep=0pt,
                      on chain, join=by arr},
  startstop/.style = {base=##1, fill=red!30},
    process/.style = {base=##1, fill=blue!30},
   decision/.style = {base=##1, sharp corners,
                      diamond, aspect=1.35, fill=green!30,
                      inner xsep=0pt},
         io/.style = {base=##1, sharp corners, 
                     trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                     fill=blue!30,},
       arr/.style = {thick,-Stealth}
        }   }
\makeatother

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
    node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
    base/.default = 54mm, % default width of nodes
      start chain = A going below
                        ]
\node [startstop]   {Start initialization of model};
\node [process]     {Initialize the operating current mode};
\node [process]     {Call the input variables of the whole system from the scripts};
\node [process]     {Call the initial setpoins for the individual components};
\node [process]     {Simulate the individual sub-systems };
\node (cal) [process]   {Calculate derivatives};
\node [process]     {Calculate output state variables};
\node (str) [process]   {Store the values in work-space};
\node (dec) [decision=6em]    {Simulation completed?};
\node [process]     {Store the iteration outputs of all state variables in work-space};
\node [process]     {Considering the stored final output state variable as initial condition for main model simulation};
%
\node (um)  [process=4em,
             suspend join,
             right=of str]   {update model};
%
\draw[arr] (dec.east) node[above right] {yes} -| (um);
\node[below right] at (dec.south) {no};
\draw[arr] (um) |- (cal);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: thank you @zarko. It looks really well structured. But when I use it, it exceeds the page so is there any way to solve it?

Comment: @Vishnu, if your really document use default page layout of `article`, this should not happen. See edited answer.

Comment: hello @zarko. Can you tell me how can i increase the box length in the above tikz picture. It would behelpful for me.

Comment: @Vishnu, change accordingly `text width=...`. it is set by by code line `base/.default = 54mm, % default width of nodes`. For example, if you like to have box length equal to 66mm, replace aforementioned code line with: `base/.default = 66mm, `